# I would like to surround all my scss-generated css with an extra class

Tags: css, sass

I have multiple scss-file in several folders. To generate one css-file i have:

```
@import 'shared/variables';
//= include folder/**/*.scss
```

Which gives in short:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  ...
}
...
```

I Would to surround this with one extra class so that the css looks like:

```css
.extraclass {
  .container {
    display: block;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Is this possible with sass or gulp?

Comment: You can't have nested classes in the compiled CSS if that's what you're asking.

Comment: It's possible in sass/scss however, the compiled css will look different. Moreover, wrapping the css class with another class will be useless if the HTML doesn't follow the same nesting pattern. Your HTML should also nest the element with class `.container` in another element with class `.extraclass`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

```
@mixin all-css {
  //= include folder/**/*.scss
}

.extraclass  {
  @include all-css;
}
```

And yes the html will follow this.